# Disabling typescript type safety check in template

Tags: vuejs2

This is specific to vue js 2 (using 2.7) using typescript and volar extension

When using `<script lang="ts">` the `<template>` content also gets typescript notifications even when the content does not support typescript

*eg.*

```html
<my-component @change="(selection)=>doStuff(selection, index)"></my-component>
```

will show error (in the IDE, but compiles and works)

> Parameter 'selection' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

adding the type makes the code invalid, because the type is not parsed

```html
<my-component @change="(selection:string)=>doStuff(selection, index)"></my-component>
```

> Unexpected token, expected "," (1:429)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this will help somebody facing the same issue

The [2.7 release blog post](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html#volar-compatibility) has these instructions for volar compatibility:

> #### Volar Compatibility
>
> 2.7 ships improved type definitions so it is no longer necessary to install @vue/runtime-dom just for Volar template type inference
> support. All you need now is the following config in tsconfig.json:
>
> ```js
> {
>   // ...
>   "vueCompilerOptions": {
>     "target": 2.7
>   }
> }
> ```

However, to suppress the typescript checking in templates, the use of `experimentalDisableTemplateSupport` option is required too

`tsconfig.json`:

```js
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "target": 2.7,
    "experimentalDisableTemplateSupport": true
  },
```